# Leaflet behaviour when in bootstrap hidden tab

Tags: tabs, leaflet, bootstrap-4

I have a problem when using leaflet and bootstrap tabs. The maps load properly but whenever I click on the marker, the map will move and shift the positions. I tried using map.invalidateSize() but it does not work. This only happens on hidden tabs. The active tab on page loading does not have this behaviour. Please help. Thank you

[When the map is load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2oJBe.png)

[When the marker is clicked.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7G4b4.png)